# yielding from generator to another generator in a same thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, generator

### Problem description

I'm trying to implement a service that loading data from remote database and write into storage at server.
For example, The client makes a rpc call like `import_data(datasource="mysql:host/db/table", storage="backend_storage"`, which returns a stream of responses to tell client process periodically.

The signature of rpc callback at server is like `def callback(request) -> Iterator[response]`, which the server provides the thread to execute callback and iterates over the return of callback and send each of them asap.

the server is a third-party framework, I cannot modify.
pseudocode like below:

```py
def service_executor(connection):
    request = connection.get_request()
    for response in callback(request):
        connection.send_response(response)
```

I'd like to implement like this:

```py
def callback(request):
    def loading_data_generator():
        for batch in loading_from_database():
            yield batch
            # can we yield a response to callback in current thread
            # yield "processed a new batch" as callback yield
    # write_to_storage is a third-party library, I cannot modify
    write_to_stroage(wrapped_iterator(loading_data_generator())
```

Since I cannot yield out of `callback` inside `loading_data_generator`, current implement will return after `write_to_storage` returns. The thread cannot get back to service_executor during `write_to_storage`.

I can arrange `write_to_storage` into a single thread and use queue to pass process into current callback to yield back to `service_executor`. Since all the operations are serial executed. Can we use a single thread to make it work.

### Expected Behavior

Expected control flow is like:

service_executor -> callback -> write_to_storage -> loading_data_generator -> yield data -> write_to_storage[write] -> loading_data_generator -> [**yield progress to service_executor**] -> service_executor[send] -> .....

Minimal code

```py
def write_to_storage(data_generator):
    for i in data_generator:
        print(f"writing {i} to storage")

def callback(request):
    def data_generator():
        for i in range(request):
            yield i
            # here I'd like to yield to service_executor
            # yield f"{i} consumed"

    write_to_storage(data_generator())

def service_executor(request):
    response =  callback(request)
    if isinstance(response, Iterable):
        for item in response:
            print(f"show response {response}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    service_executor(5)
```

Expected:

```
writing 0 to storage
show response 0 consumed
writing 1 to storage
show response 1 consumed
writing 2 to storage
show response 2 consumed
writing 3 to storage
show response 3 consumed
writing 4 to storage
show response 4 consumed
```

### Attempts

#### 1st time

I'm trying to wrap the whole callback logic into async function with a event loop executing in current thread, but don't know how to yield a async task result when it is done.

```py
def callback(request):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    q = asyncio.Queue()

    def load_from_database():
        for batch in loading_data_generator():
            yield batch
            asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(q.put("process a new batch"))
    async def wrap_writing_into_async():
        write_to_storage(wrap_iterator(load_from_database())

    loop.create_task(wrap_writing_into_async())

    # try to get from q and yield
    while True:
        task = loop.create_task(q.get())
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
        yield task.result()
```

But it does not work as expected, the thread stuck at `loop.run_until_complete` until `wrap_writing_into_async` done.

#### 2nd time

I found a library called [greenback](https://github.com/oremanj/greenback), which can call async coro from sync context, also, [link](https://techbrij.com/python-async_generator-from-sync-function) gives a way to convert an async generator into a sync one.
Somehow, I can achieve my goal

```py
def iter_over_async(ait, loop):
    ait = ait.__aiter__()

    async def get_next():
        try:
            obj = await ait.__anext__()
            return False, obj
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            return True, None

    while True:
        done, obj = loop.run_until_complete(get_next())
        if done:
            break
        yield obj

def write_to_storage(data_generator):
    for i in data_generator:
        print(f"writing {i} to storage")

def callback(request):

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    q = asyncio.Queue(1)

    def g():
        for i in range(10):
            yield i
            greenback.await_(q.put(f"we have processed {i}"))
        greenback.await_(q.join())

    async def wrap_consumer():
        await greenback.ensure_portal()
        write_to_storage(g())

    t = loop.create_task(wrap_consumer())

    async def q_get():
        while True:
            yield await q.get()
            q.task_done()

    yield from iter_over_async(q_get(), loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(t)

def service_executor(request):
    response = callback(request)
    if isinstance(response, Iterable):
        for item in response:
            print(f"show response {item}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    service_executor(5)
```

But the queue is not limited to only 1 element, `write_to_storage` always iterates 3 times before `g_get` yields.

```
writing 0 to storage
writing 1 to storage
writing 2 to storage
show response we have processed 0
writing 3 to storage
show response we have processed 1
writing 4 to storage
show response we have processed 2
writing 5 to storage
show response we have processed 3
writing 6 to storage
show response we have processed 4
writing 7 to storage
show response we have processed 5
writing 8 to storage
show response we have processed 6
writing 9 to storage
show response we have processed 7
show response we have processed 8
show response we have processed 9
```

Also, `q_get` needs a way to stop iteration for some unique object to indicate.

Comment: (1) What is `wrapped_iterator`? (2) If I understand correctly you want to run two iterators/generators. One loads from database and feeds `write_to_storage`. The other is `callback` (or returned by it) and should wait until the first iterator is asked to yield a new item. Then other yields a response which shows the progress of the operation. Right? This sounds like a job for a second thread and a queue (as you already wrote) but there is some problem with blocking the `service_executor` (its thread) which I haven't understood yet.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelButscher (1) wrapped_iterator is generate a iterator into a class object, the downstream write_to_stroage accepts, you can simple think it does nothing. (2)  I'd like to make the logic run in a single thread, so that if the client disconnect, the thread is join by the server framework. The key point it to yield a response, skipping write_to_storage, at callback.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I've update with a minimal code, you may check in Expected Behavior section

Comment: Do you control `write_to_storage`?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg No, `write_to_storage` is a third party api accepts iterator to loading data

Comment: I think this is not possible with a single thread, neither async will work. Switching between async tasks is only possible if the execution stack of the task only contains async functions. If there is a synchronous function like `write_to_storage` or `service_executor` in the stack it must return first before switching to another task/stack is possible.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Somehow, I made a runnable example in 2nd attempt section. But the code is not neat at all obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Asyncio only makes sense when you have two tasks that need to run concurrently.  The same thing applies to clones or third-party implementations.  Your description of your desired output says you want the print statements to appear in a well-defined sequence.  If I understand your requirements correctly, you don't need concurrent execution.  It only makes your program more complicated than it needs to be.

I see that you have an iterator, which you've already written; it gets passed as an argument to a function you cannot modify.  Every time this iterator yields, you want to execute some sort of progress notification.  That's how I interpret your problem.  If you can let go of the idea that your program must consist of two nested iterators, this can be done by simply calling a progress function after each yield:

```
def write_to_storage(dgen):
    for i in dgen:
        print(f"writing {i} to storage")
        
def acknowledge(s):
    print(f"show response {s}")

def data_generator(request_count):
    for i in range(request_count):
        yield i
        # After each yield, make an acknowledgement
        acknowledge(f"{i} consumed")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_to_storage(data_generator(5))
```

That's a complete, runnable program that gives exactly the output that you want.  It doesn't need a third party tool or in fact any import at all.

If you must have an iterator, you need to accept the idea that Python cannot yield from the inner of two nested iterators back to the outer calling function. You say this yourself.  It's impossible because subroutines in Python (as in most modern languages) are organized into a stack, and the execution path of a single thread must follow a logical  sequence.

You can certainly make two iterators play together, but one of them has to be "unrolled."  This iterator advances by explicit calls to its `send` method.  This is another working program, which again gives exactly the result you want:

```
def write_to_storage(dgen):
    for i in dgen:
        print(f"writing {i} to storage")

def an_iterator():
    s = ''
    while True:
        s = yield
        if s is None:
            break
        print(f"show response {s}")
        
def data_generator(request_count, iter1):
    for i in range(request_count):
        yield i
        iter1.send(f"{i} consumed")
    
def main():
    iter1 = an_iterator()
    iter1.send(None)
    write_to_storage(data_generator(5, iter1))
    try:
        iter1.send(None)
    except StopIteration:
        print("Finished")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of the simple function call to acknowledge(), this example steps the outer iterator one tick by calling its `send` method.  It works but I wouldn't do it this way unless there is a compelling reason for the extra complexity.